# Como puedo generar un apk para probar mi app en react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

tengo un proyecto hecho con react-native y lo he estado probando con expo, pero quiero generar un apk para poder verlo en un dispositivo pero no se como hacerlo, la documentacion de react no es muy clara ya que solo me explica como generar un apk listo para mostrar a la play store y por ahora solo quiero una en version debug para hacer pruebas

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Leandro te sugiero revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio. ¿Que no es muy claro?, ¿Que problema tienes?, porque no agregas esa información. Te sugiero realizar también el [tour] del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto explica cómo funciona para generar un APK utilizando Expo y la referencia es la guía oficial de [expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html#5-test-it-on-your-device-or-simulator)

Lo primero es instalar la herramienta exp haciendo:

```
npm install -g exp
```

Después configuras tu archivo app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
  "name": "Your App Name",
  "icon": "./path/to/your/app-icon.png",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "slug": "your-app-slug",
  "sdkVersion": "17.0.0",
  "ios": {
    "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
  },
  "android": {
    "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
  }
}
}
```

Ejecutas el siguiente comando para probar tu proyecto

```
exp start
```

Si todo fue bien ahora ejecutas el siguiente comando

```
exp build:android
```

En este punto te preguntara si tienes algún keystore listo para generar tu APK. Si no tienes idea que es un keystore entonces elige que Expo gestiones el keystore por ti.

Después de determinar que keystore utilizar generará un APK con la infraestructura de Expo y debe tardar unos 10 min aproximadamente
Puedes monitorear tu creación con el siguiente comando:

```
exp build:status
```

Cuando esté listo, te regresará un link que te dirigirá a tu descarga del APK. Este APK es ya un release y te puede servir para probar en tus dispositivos aunque aún no tengas una cuenta en la Play Store de Google.

Comment: me da problemas al utilizar npm install -g exp no instala las dependencias me dice: npm ERR! Expected: e6c37c74c2ede6c32f04b13d30383e10255908d3,  npm ERR! Actual:   6bb5a42aa7d85b993db244095018c2a71391adef
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/@expo/ngrok/-/ngrok-2.3.0.tgz
 y aparte de que se pueda instalar esa dependencia no me queda claro lo del slug como puedo saber mi version o mejor dicho que colocar alli?

Comment: El slug es el nombre que le darás a tu aplicación dentro de expo

Sobre el problema con el npm posiblemente sea un problema de versiones de tu npm.

Comment: actualice mi version del node y me funciono todo lo que dijiste, gracias

Answer (score 0):

- Puedes ejecutar el app directamente en tu dispositivo activando el
  modo USB Debugger y conectándolo a tu máquina. Cierra todos lo
  emuladores y verifica en una terminal si aparece en la lista con
  `adb devices`.
- Puedes revisar dentro de tu proyecto si en el directorio
  android/build/outputs/apk/ se genera el app-debug.apk, puedes
  importarlo al dispositivo e instalarlo.